# Can I use Javascript to trigger a method in my MVC controller?

Tags: javascript, asp.net-mvc-3

I have a controller for "Question" objects; if these Questions are of Type "MultipleChoice" then I want to be able to add a collection of "MultipleChoiceOption" objects to the Question... so far, so good.

The problem I have is that when I edit a Question, change it's type to MultipleChoice, then add options, it is necessary to return to the Edit Question view and commit the edited question, otherwise the change in Question.Type is lost.  Obviously this is a little annoying, so what I'd like to do is hook up a method that fires the relevant method in the QuestionController whenever the dropdownlist value is changed.

I have the following in my Edit Question View:

```
@Html.DropDownListFor(model => model.Type, Helper.GetSelectList(), new { id = "QuestionTypeDropDown", onchange = "OnChange();" })

<script type="text/javascript">


function OnChange(text) {
    ...do something here

        }

    }
</script>
```

and this method in my Question Controller:

```
[HttpPost]
    public ActionResult QuestionTypeEdited(Question question)
    {
        if (ModelState.IsValid)
        {
            SaveQuestion(question, false);
            return RedirectToAction("Edit", "Question", new { id = question.OwningPulseId });
        }
        return View(question);
    }
```

But I don't know how to hook them up.  I tried one method using Ajax that I found online, but this just stopped the js from firing at all (perhaps I don't have Ajax? Sorry I don't know anything about Ajax so that may be a dumb statement!).  Is it possible using "simple" Javascript?

If I need to specify the controller explicitly, please be sure to mention how if you know :-)

Cheers

Comment: It won't be super simple, but it is possible with javascript and AJAX. If you have javascript, you can use Asynchronous Javascript And XML.

Answer (score 1):

This is a very basic example of what you could do. (hasn't been tested)

The javascript:

```
// wire up your change event unobtrusively with jQuery
$("#Type").change(function() {
  // find the form that the select belongs to and serialize it
  var question = $(this).closest("form").serialize();
  // POST the form data to your controller
  $.post("Question/QuestionTypeEdited", question, function(data) {
      // this function executes when the POST completes
      // if data has a RedirectUrl, redirect
      if (data.RedirectUrl)
      {
         window.location = data.RedirectUrl;
      }
      else
      {
         // display any errors - I'm using alert because its very simple, you'll probably want to use a div
         alert(data.Errors);
      }
  });
});
```

Here's the action:

```
[HttpPost]
public ActionResult QuestionTypeEdited(Question question)
{
    if (ModelState.IsValid)
    {
        SaveQuestion(question, false);

        // return a JSON result with a redirect url
        return Json(new {RedirectUrl = "Edit/Question/"+question.OwningPulseId});
    }

    // return a JSON result with the errors
    return Json(new {Errors = ModelState.Errors});
}
```

References:

- [jQuery change](http://api.jquery.com/change/)
- [jQuery closest](http://api.jquery.com/closest/)
- [jQuery serialie](http://api.jquery.com/serialize/)
- [jQuery post](http://api.jquery.com/jQuery.post/)
- [Controller.Json](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.web.mvc.controller.json%28v=vs.108%29.aspx)

Comment: I don't seem to have a .serialize option appearing in Intellisense; when I tried this method, nothing happened, so I assume it's causing an error in Javascript.

Answer (score 0):

If you want to get just the postback to your controller when the ddl changed, you can just do this:

```
<script type="text/javascript">

function OnChange() {
    document.forms[0].submit();

    }
</script>
```

Assuming you are within a form:

```
@using (Html.BeginForm())
```

You will get the value from your DropDownListFor to the [HttpPost] Controller